# Why was the vegetarian question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Seeing as how Caleb is always willing to give his keyboard a good whipping to explain his closures, I was hoping he could explain his reasoning for closing this question:

[What does the Bible say about vegetarian diets?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32141/what-does-the-bible-say-about-vegetarian-diets/)

Flimzy cast a close vote as well, which I voiced disagreement in the comments, and the issue seems to be a broader meta issue, [which Flimzy has headed up resolving.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/biblical-basis-vs-what-the-bible-says-about-a-subject) Perhaps more than Flimzy and I can weigh in there. It might help us resolve this specific meta post.

Comment: We need a consensus on the whole "What does the Bible say about X" issue.  I know which side you're one. I'm on the opposite, and I just finally posted an opposing answer [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/biblical-basis-vs-what-the-bible-says-about-a-subject/3973#3973).  I've set that META post to be a featured post to try to see what the consensus comes down to, since neither of the existing answers is a clear winner.

Comment: That said, even by my own belief that "What does the bible say about X" is a bad idea, the post you ask about here is salvaged by asking if there is a verse that says we're permitted to eat meat.  There is, and so that portion of the question is clearly, definitively answerable.  However, the title is out of sync with that portion of the question, so I think the title should be edited before it gets reopened.

Comment: Short version: I read it as a truth question. It seemed less about Christianity (or even vegetarianism) and more about whether it was right or wrong to kill animals.